# Swift Generic approach to NSCoding

Tags: ios, swift, oop, generics, inheritance

I have a bunch of model classes, which all need to implement the `NSCoding` protocol. They all use the ObjectMapper framework so the `NSCoding` bit can be done to and from the JSON Data.

Now I want to do this generically but I can't seem to be able to create inherited mapper instances : `Mapper<Mappable> --> Mapper<MyMappableModelClass>`.

So I need to do a hack to be able to do it all in the super class. Now my super class needs to know all child classes which is very bad design:

```
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    var object: NSDictionary!

    switch self {
    case let u as User:
        object = Mapper<User>().toJSON(u)
    case let p as Profile:
        object = Mapper<Profile>().toJSON(p)
    // 
    // ...
    // 

    default:
        fatalError("Add your class to RestObject.swift")
    }

    aCoder.encodeObject(object, forKey: "json")
}
```

So basically how can I create a `Mapper<ChildClass>` instance at runtime, without having to implement the `NSCoding` protocol in every single one of my model classes?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue here, try to give a chance to our solution into [relative ObjectMapper issue conversation](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/issues/154#issuecomment-341164964)